# Grid view with row headers to split groups

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am looking to find out how i can separate up my results in my gridview like below (please run snippet to see my desired result).

I am adding gridview like below.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" CssClass="gvadmin"  PageSize="19" AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="gv_PageChanging" AutoGenerateSelectButton="true" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" OnRowEditing="gv_RowEdit" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gv_SelectChanged" />
```

Filling the gridview from sql connection stored in class.

```
gv.DataSource = c.sqldt
gv.DataBind()
```

This populates the gridview with no issues but i dont know how to add in the sub headers for the type. I have seen someone else do it before but i am not sure how.

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>ID</td>
<td>type</td>
<td>name</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Person</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>person</td>
<td>John</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>person</td>
<td>Amy</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>animal</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>animal</td>
<td>Max</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td>animal</td>
<td>fifi</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want headers for each type as it gets to it.

The data would be sql driven so using a sql query and i have no issue getting the data to the gridview but how do i add the "type" headers to break them up.

i have tried the following using multiple datatables into 1 dataset but cannot get this to work.

```
        Dim sqlstr As String = "select distinct(type) from typestbl order by type"
    Dim sqlstr2 As String = "select Names,Age from Typestbl order by names where type = @type"


    Dim i As Integer = 0
    s.FillDS(sqlstr)
    For Each row As DataRow In s.sqldt.Rows

        dt = New DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add("Names")
        dt.Columns.Add("Age")
        Dim r As DataRow = dt.NewRow
        r("Names") = row.Item(0).ToString
        r("Age") = ""
        dt.Rows.Add(r)


        ds.Merge(dt)

        s.FillDS2()
        ds.Merge(s.sqldt2)

    Next

    gv.DataSource = ds
    gv.DataBind()
```

Comment: Usually, Stack Overflow is _not_ a free coding service.

Comment: Basically you can use two ways: create a datatable in you server code that contain data similar to your example or to have some javascript (threre are libraries you can use se e.g. [jspreadsheets](https://jspreadsheets.com/)).  If you are not experienced with javascript the first one are more simple, but both are too broad for a single SO question.

Comment: Thank you for your reponse IvanH. My problem is how to create a datatable in that format.

I have a table with three colums. Type, Names, Age

I need to display the results with headings. 

animals
fifi - 4
max - 7

People
john -30
amy - 25

I am struggling to explain properly. 

so far i have tried adding multiple datatables to a dataset in a loop but this has not worked. 

I have added code that i have tried to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Queueid,queueitem,queuedata,itemgrouptype,itemgroup from queueitems order by itemgrouptype,itemgroup", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    adp.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    string first = "";
    for(int i=0;i<ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;i++)
    {

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][3].ToString() != first)
        {
            DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
            dr[0] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][3].ToString();
            first = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][3].ToString();
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.InsertAt(dr, i);

        }

    }
    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: I will try that now. Thank you. Just working on converting it to vb. Will update after i have tried.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain. can anyone help me convert this bit to vb.net

    for(int i=0;i<ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;i++)
    {
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][3].ToString() != first)
    {
    DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
    dr[0] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][3].ToString();
    first = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][3].ToString();
    ds.Tables[0].Rows.InsertAt(dr, i);
    }
    }

sorry. for some reason i cant get this to go to a code block.

Comment: there are alot of online converters available.

Comment: I got it. first two converters failed me. thank you so much.Perfect response. You have saved me. Cheers Gagan Deep